# Mailserver postfix+dovecot: use multiple certificates/combine certificates?

Tags: postfix, dovecot, certificate

**UPDATED TO CLARIFY**

OK, so I have this Postfix/Dovecot combo running nicely, using virtual domains and virtual users through mysql. Now the problem is to provide TLS I have to point my users to my.hostname.com since that is the certificate.

This presents some problems, since when I want to move to another server they would have to change all their client's settings, I can't just move the certificates and change the DNS MX records to point to another IP address. Also, most e-mail clients start looking at mail.domain.com when configuring an IMAP address, now I have to explicitely tell them to use a different hostname.

But, in both postfix and dovecot, you can only select one certificate (I use Let's Encrypt). I've looked into SNI for dovecot, but since client adoption is quite poor I don't want to go that way and postfix doesn't support it at all as far as I can find.

So basically, when I set up a domain on my server, I generate a certificate through certbot and all is well, but I can't use that per-domain certificate for both the MUA and the MTA (well I could, but that would eliminate all other ones). I know there are providers that do this, I just can't figure out how.

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO ACCOMPLISH**

I would like for clients to be able to just use mail.theirdomain.com as the IMAP and SMTP server in stead of having to point them to my.hostname.com. Right now I have to do that since dovecot can only use one certificate (except if you use SNI, which I don't want to since client adoption is poor). Then when they use mail.theirdomain.com the certificate should have that domain/host in the certificate.

Is it possible for instance to combine multiple PEM files into one and point dovecot or postfix to that one? Or am I viewing this all wrong?

Comment: Your post is somewhat confusing. I say that because you say what you can’t do, which is exactly what you should do, and it’s not clear why you can’t? What is the problem with creating a certificate for mail.domain.com, and updating DNS accordingly? If you want to move servers, move the certificate. Why can’t you? If you have multiple servers use a wildcard cert, subject alternative names, or a load balancer that terminates connections at a single point.

Comment: You're right. Let me take a moment to update it.